# Explain this regex interpretation by go

Tags: regex, go

package main

Consider the following code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[A-Z]*")
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABcd", "."))
}
```

It outputs:

> .c.d.

I've tested my regex and string on [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/). It should only match `AB`. What does it match between `c` and `d` that go inserts a `.` there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ABcd` string is seen by a regex engine as

```
EMPTY_STRING A EMPTY_STRING B EMPTY_STRING c EMPTY_STRING d EMPTY_STRING
```

The `[A-Z]*` matches *zero or more* ASCII uppercase letters. That is, it may match `EMTPY_STRING`. It works like this:

```
EMPTY_STRING A EMPTY_STRING B EMPTY_STRING c EMPTY_STRING d EMPTY_STRING
| ------------- First match ------------ |   |-2nd one-|    |-3rd one-|
```

Resulting in `.c.d.`.

Thus, you should consider using `+` or `{1,}` quantifier instead of `*` (= `{0,}`).

Answer (score 4):

The `*` in your regexp matches *zero* or more occurances of capital letters, of which there are two after the initial run of two (AB).
Change it to a `+` for *one* or more occurances.